# Viewer quality settings (for one viewer on the page)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have two viewers on the same page. And I want to set performance settings for only one viewer with following code:

```
this.viewer.setQualityLevel(false, false);
this.viewer.setGroundShadow(false);
this.viewer.setGroundReflection(false);
this.viewer.setProgressiveRendering(true);
```

BUT (!) settings are applied for both viewers for some reason. Is there any way to apply them only for one viewer on the page?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Also try the [Profile API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/ProfileSettings/) to persist settings - you can get the current profile with:

```
viewer.profile
```

I was unable to replicate the issue unfortunately ... looking at your code did you assign two viewers to the same handle? can you post your code to initialize viewers? what version of viewer btw?

[image]

Comment: I am using https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js.

Comment: It is hard to post the code with viewers initialization, I am using my own Angular wrappers and it is two separate components, so it is definitely not one instance of the viewer. Actually, I think Petr is right about bug with local storage, try to refresh the page after applying settings for the second viewer, both viewers will be with same settings. I can reproduce it using NOP_VIEWER variable in runtime (seems it handles the last viewer on the page): (1) NOP_VIEWER.setGroundShadow(false) (2) last viewer on the page is without shadow (3) refresh page (4) both viewers are without a shadow

Comment: sorry didn’t occur to me that it happened when the page gets reloaded and yes Petr’s workaround is great - we will let engineering know to fix this - you may also use localStorage/cookie to persist your own settings for each viewer and recover them programmatically upon reload.

Answer (score 0):

The viewer settings are kept in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), so changing them using methods like `viewer.setQualityLevel` probably propagates the updates to other viewer instances as well. Let me discuss this behavior with the dev team as (I think) it could be considered a bug.

In the meantime, if you need to change settings for a single instance of the viewer, consider using "lower level" methods that don't use the local storage. For example, instead of `viewer.setQualityLevel(useSAO, useFXAA)` you could use `viewer.impl.togglePostProcess(useSAO, useFXAA)`, and instead of `viewer.setGroundShadow(bool)` you could use `viewer.impl.toggleGroundShadow(bool)`.

Comment: Petr, thanks for the workaround! If Bryan confirms it is a bug, I will use these methods waiting for the fix